# SQL Group Twice, Distinct Row

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I am using SQL Azure. I am trying to group a set of results twice, so that the user name field is unique. In my results, the same rows appear several times with a different value for transaction count.

Here is my code:

```
select settings.UserName, SUM(TransactionCount) as TransactionCount, settings.SettingValue as    Sku, CASE 
WHEN settings.SettingValue = 'cccmicro' AND TransactionCount > 1800 THEN 'True'
WHEN settings.SettingValue = 'cccsub1' AND TransactionCount > 6000 THEN 'True'
WHEN settings.SettingValue = 'cccsub2' AND TransactionCount > 18000 THEN 'True'
WHEN settings.SettingValue = 'cccsub3' AND TransactionCount > 30000 THEN 'True' 
ELSE 'False'
END As [Over]
from jma_qb_trans_count trans
Inner Join jma_settings settings on settings.UserName = trans.UserName
where settings.SettingName = 'QB:JMAWebStoreSku' and settings.SettingValue != ''
Group by settings.UserName, settings.SettingValue, settings.SettingName, TransactionCount
Order By settings.UserName
```

Here is my data:

[image]

Here is what I'm seeking:

UserName: james.dick
TransactionCount: 8
Sku: cloudcartconnectorlicense
Over: False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the code below. I think it will work like you asked.

```
select 

settings.UserName, 
CASE 
WHEN settings.SettingValue = 'cccmicro' AND TransactionCount > 1800 THEN 'True'
WHEN settings.SettingValue = 'cccsub1' AND TransactionCount > 6000 THEN 'True'
WHEN settings.SettingValue = 'cccsub2' AND TransactionCount > 18000 THEN 'True'
WHEN settings.SettingValue = 'cccsub3' AND TransactionCount > 30000 THEN 'True' 
ELSE 'False'
END As [Over],
SUM(TransactionCount) as TransactionCount, 
settings.SettingValue as Sku

from jma_qb_trans_count trans
Inner Join jma_settings settings on settings.UserName = trans.UserName
where settings.SettingName = 'QB:JMAWebStoreSku' and settings.SettingValue != ''
Group by 1,2
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get Msg 164, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

Comment: I see. Try to change Group by 1,2 to Group by 1

Answer (score 0):

Your group by is splitting the results put them in the select part and you will see
  why query does not work correctly.

```
Group by settings.UserName, settings.SettingValue, settings.SettingName, TransactionCount
```